# WebDeploy with TypeScript includes wrong files

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, webdeploy, typescript1.8

I've recently started working on an MVC project in Visual Studio using TypeScript for the frontend development. I'm not sure exactly what the standard is, but I chose to put my TypeScript in a folder called `Frontend` at the root of the project (primarily to avoid another issue w/ building not working right when it was in `Scripts` directly). Using the `.tfconfig` (I believe this is a 1.8 feature), I have the `outDir` set to `/Scripts/app`.  On my local environment, everything is building and deploying to IISExpress as expected; no problems yet.

However, when I try to run a WebDeploy on this project, specifically from my CI server, I'm seeing failures due to missing files. Specifically, instead of just trying to copy over js files from `Scripts`, it is also looking for a counterpart script for every ts source file I have in the `Frontend` directory. This seems like an issue with the WebDeploy process, but I haven't been able to find a way to avoid it, or tell it not to include that directory (or figure out why it even looks there).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with Typescript 1.8 and Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online) build CI.  I found related discussions on Github, for example [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5894) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6467)

What fixed it for me was removing `"outDir": "./Scripts"` field from the `tsconfig.json` file

Comment: If you remove the outDir, do you have another method to control the output? I haven't had a chance to look through the linked issues, so I haven't been able to figure out why what you're suggesting here would help.

Comment: By removing the outDir from config file, the javascript files are generated in the same folder then I use Gulp to copy to an output directory.  You can use Gulp, Grunt, Webpack,etc to move the javascript files.

It's definitely a workaround, the referred discussions on Github in my answer state that the issue was solved in an earlier version of Typescript but looks like the Webdeploy configuration is breaking things up